# AJAXifying voting in Rails 4 using Thumbs_up gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to do a very simple voting module with an AJAX call. Unfortunately I've been stuck with this for about 4 days now. I'm still very new to Rails and I'd love to figure out what I'm doing wrong here!

The concept of the website is pretty straightforward. There's a list of posts (called Topic) that users can vote on. I've used Devise for user models and Thumbs_up for voting.

Here's the view snippet: index.html.erb

```
<td id='topic_<%=topic.id%>_votes'> <%= pluralize(topic.votes.count, "vote") %> </td>
<td><%= link_to('Vote for this post!', vote_up_topic_path(topic), :method => :post, :remote     => true) %></td>
```

Here's the controller: topics_controller.rb

```
def vote_up
  current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@topic = Topic.find(params[:id]))
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Here's the JavaScript: vote_up.js.erb in views/topics

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])) %>
  $('topic_<%=@topic.id%>_votes').html('<%= pluralize(@topic.votes.count, "vote") %>');
<% else %>
  alert("You can only vote on <%= @topic.title %> once!")
<% end %>
```

When I start up the Rails server and click on the vote link, I can see (in the terminal) that it does process the vote_up.js.erb file, but there's no change in the browser. Only when I refresh it, does it show the increased number of votes. The vote is being recorded in the DB but there's no acknowledgement of it in the browser.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ID for that Div, add a '#' before topic_<%=@topic.id%>_votes in your vote_up.js.erb code.

This is how it should be:

```
$('#topic_<%=@topic.id%>_votes').html('<%= pluralize(@topic.votes.count, "vote") %>');
```

Comment: Omg. Senior moment :( Thanks for the help!